# action bar with overflow in combination with layouts

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Hello i am a beginner in android and i have question about action Bar with Action overflow in combination with fragments.
The application that i trying to make is made of three separate layouts, and i am having trouble to display an action bar on top of these layouts.

I managed to make one app that have 3 layouts, and also to make other app that have action bar with action overflow, but I do not know how to combine these two into one application.
I was looking for answers but i haven't found some that would solve my problem.
This is my first question so i hope that I've managed to describe what is problem that i need to solve. 
Thanks to everyone who tried to help me to solve the problem.

This is my code from app one(3 layouts in fragments)

Fragment layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="second layout - layout B"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code for fragment:

```
package com.example.mp.app;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml code:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/pager"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

And MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.mp.app;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager viewPager = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));

    makeActionOverflowMenuShown();
}

private void makeActionOverflowMenuShown() {
    //devices with hardware menu button (e.g. Samsung Note) don't show action overflow menu
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("TAG", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    menu.clear();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "get Item is called                " + i);
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (i == 0){
        fragment = new FragmentA();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "get Item is called             A             " + i);
    }
    if (i == 1){
        fragment = new FragmentB();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "get Item is called             B             " + i);
    }
    if (i == 2){
        fragment = new FragmentC();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "get Item is called             C             " + i);
    }

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "get Count is called");
    return 3;
}
}
```

And this is the example i have used for action bar with action overflow:

part 1: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html
part 2: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Comment: Can I know why are you using two different apps? I did not understand what do you mean by apps here. Do they mean two different projects/applications?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote app i should write a project.
The only reason why i was using two projects is because in the first one i was practiced project with the three screens (three fragments or three layouts), and in the second one the idea was to create an action bar with action overflow. 

But now I'm trying to create a new project in which I will have these two options in one.

Comment: ok. Action overflow you will get by default write? In the activity extend it to ActionBarActivity, thats sufficient right?

Comment: I will add my comment as an answer please accept it as an answer.

Comment: I'm new to this site so I do not know what I need to do in order to accept the answer.
And I have another question, when I changed In the activity to extend it to ActionBarActivity, I only see action bar with the name of the project but not the action overflow (three dots with additional options)

Comment: You will get it just make sure you have onOptionsCreated menu method is there.. Up vote my answer.. Just take ur cursor below down arrow you will get a check mark click that.. Check other answers you will get an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get ActionBar overlay by default in Android, You need to just inherit(extend) your Activity class to ActionBarActvity class. You should override onCreateOptionsMenu method also.